# Case sensitive column drop operation for pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

From some brief testing, it appears that the column drop function for pyspark dataframes is not case sensitive, eg.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import sys

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("my-session").getOrCreate()

dff = sparkSession.createDataFrame([(10,123), (14,456), (16,678)], ["age", "AGE"])

>>> dff.show()
+---+---+
|age|AGE|
+---+---+
| 10|123|
| 14|456|
| 16|678|
+---+---+

>>> dff.drop("AGE")
DataFrame[]

>>> dff_dropped = dff.drop("AGE")
>>> dff_dropped.show()
++
||
++
||
||
||
++

"""
What I'd like to see here is:
+---+
|age|
+---+
| 10|
| 14|
| 16|
+---+
"""
```

Is there a way to drop dataframe columns in a case sensitive way? (Have seen some comments related to something like this in spark [JIRA discussions](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17041?focusedCommentId=15420952&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-15420952), but was looking for something at only applied to the `drop()` operation in an ad hoc way (**not a global / persistent setting**)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#Add this before using drop
sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=true")
```

> You need to set casesensitivity as true if you have two columns having
>   same name

Comment: Is this something that is persistent (ie. would I need to call `sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false")` in the line after the `drop()` for dataframe operations to behave as they were before)?

Comment: Note for anyone finding this answer: From my code in the original post, you'd also need to do `from pyspark.sql import SQLContext` and `sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkSession.sparkContext)` to use the `sqlContext` object that this answer uses.